# Is there any way to bypass this Firefox fullscreen security policy?

Tags: javascript, firefox, fullscreen

Recently I have been attempting to fix this bug pertaining a `requestFullscreen()` call being denied on a `<video>` element after a Tab key press. This error is only local to Firefox, and I know the Firefox constraints to be much stricter when it comes to the Fullscreen API. Many questions regarding this issue and Firefox have already been asked on SO, and I believe to have applied all potential solutions to no avail.

Our application allows clients to use a remote control to record a video. This input on the remote control should also induce a `requestFullscreen()` call, as a `click` event on the fullscreen button is emitted right after remote control input. Because Firefox perceives this "utility" key input of `Tab` sent from the remote control to be a security hazard or "non user-activated", it denies this request. Timings also show the duration of the operations contained in the event listener to be negligible. I was able to conclude this (and other things) through attempting the following:

- Observing previously added timings made by a colleague
- Trimming off any other operation besides the requestFullscreen() function
- Relayed/emitted a keydown event from a tab input, essentially
  “converting” the key input to become legal Enter and/or R input
- Checked whether returned requestFullscreen() Promise errored
- Changed key listener to listen to CTRL or ALT to confirm whether it behaved the same, which it did
- Added `setTimeout(element.click(), 5000)` to split the tab keypress and recording operations from the `requestFullscreen()` call
- Isolating `requestFullscreen()` call completely by commenting out all other previous operations/function calls
- Added and used the browser-specific calls for `requestFullscreen()` (webkit, ms, moz)

The only thing that seems to work is manually re-engaging/activating the webpage by clicking any element on the page, before subsequently attempting another fullscreen request with a Tab key input. I have attempted to `Element.focus()` any element on the webpage before calling `requestFullscreen()`, but also to no avail. This unconfirmed [Bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1654480) describes the same woes to the tee.

Therefore, my question is: **Is there any way to bypass this security policy in order to make Tab a "legal" input for `requestFullscreen()`?** I know I might be hopelessly fighting browser design here, but the client seems a little too fond of this browser. I hope to be able to receive some input regarding this before looking for a solution outside the browser, or even advising against the use of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Feature-Policy: fullscreen ;
You can try

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).